# R1C1 integers into formula

Tags: vba, excel

Hello do you know how to set r1 r2 r3 numbers into R1C1 formula to have no errors? thanks

```
Sub ReapplyFormula()

Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer

r1 = Range("Range1").row + 1 - Range("EndTable").row
r2 = Range("Range2").row + 1 - Range("EndTable").row
r3 = Range("Range3").row - Range("EndTable").row

For i = Range("Start").Column To Range("End").Column - 1

Cells(Range("End").row, i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(SUM(R[r1]C:R[-1]C) = SUM(R[r2]C:R[r3]C),0, SUM(R[r1]C:R[-1]C) - SUM(R[r2]C:R[r3]C))"

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Was the below answer useful

Comment: Can you or someone specify what he is trying to achieve? Because it doesn't get that clear from his question.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should be:

```
"=IF(SUM(R[" & r1 & "]C:R[-1]C) = _
SUM(R[" & r2 & "]C:R[" & r3 & "]C),0, _
SUM(R[" & r1 & "]C:R[-1]C) - _
SUM(R[" & r2 & "]C:R[" & r3 & "]C))"
```

If you want to add variables into a `String` you need to end the string `"` use `&` to add to the string then the variable `r1` add again `&` and continue the `String` `"`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me like you want **relative** row numbers, so your code should not be using [] - it would look like:

```
Cells(Range("End").row, i).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(SUM(R" & r1 & "C:R[-1]C) = SUM(R" & r2 & "C:R" & r3 & "C),0, SUM(R" & r1 & "C:R[-1]C) - SUM(R" & r2 & "C:R" & r3 & "C))"
```